# How to save a numeric value in a specified location of a CSV file inside for loops in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, csv, for-loop, memory, optimization

I want to do this because otherwise I run out of memory to save the values in a matrix, as the dimensions of the matrix increases.

For example,

```
for a=1:10000
   for b=1:10000
      M(a,b)=rand;
   end
end
```

Here, the system runs out of memory as it can't store a 10000x10000 matrix.

So, I want to keep writing the `(a,b)`'th value inside the for loops into the `(a,b)`'th cell of a csv file (or an xls file, whatever). How do I do that?

I want something like this:

```
for a=1:10000
   for b=1:10000
      xlswrite1('file.xls',a,b,rand); % better if I can get a solution with csvwrite, as I prefer CSVs to work with
   end
end
```

But this obviously doesn't work. The error it gives is:

```
Error using evalin
Undefined function or variable 'Excel'.

Error in xlswrite1 (line 2)
Excel=evalin('caller','Excel');
```

Then when I add the following lines according to [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/130487) article,

```
Excel = actxserver ('Excel.Application');
File='datafile.xls';
if ~exist(File,'file')
ExcelWorkbook = Excel.workbooks.Add;
ExcelWorkbook.SaveAs(File,1);
ExcelWorkbook.Close(false);
```

it gives this error:

```
Error using xlswrite1 (line 82)
Range argument must a string of Excel A1 notation.
```

Can anyone please suggest a simple solution? I can't find any from my online search so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using *dlmwrite*. But I suggest you to write row by row instead of element by element.

```
  N = 100 ;
  M = zeros(N,N) ;
  filename = 'test.csv';
  for a=1:N
     for b=1:N
        M(a,b)=rand;
     end
     dlmwrite(filename,M(a,:),'-append')
  end
```

If you don't want to make a matrix *M*, then make rows and write them to your file:

```
N = 100 ;
M = zeros(1,N) ;
filename = 'test.csv';
for a=1:N
   for b=1:N
      M(1,b)=rand;
   end
   dlmwrite(filename,M(1,:),'-append')       
end
```

Comment: But here you are creating the matrix M anyway, so memory is getting used in it, which is what I wanted to evade.

Comment: Added it in the answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It works. But I have an auxiliary question. I notice that using dlmwrite, the code takes 101.95 seconds to finish running, whereas with only M (i.e., no writing to file), it takes 67.53 seconds. That's 50.97% longer time! Why is there such a drastic time increase when writing to file? I know writing to file takes time, but so much? Is it the case that every time `dlmwrite` is called, it checks to see if the file exists, etc? If so, can this file writing be optimized by, say, creating and opening the file in the beginning, and not checking if the file exists inside the loop?

Comment: This options comes with fopen/fprintf but not with dlmwrite...I think.

Comment: Ok. Then, would you have any idea how to make this code not take so long to run? Its taking this time only for M=100. For my case, M is actually = 10000. So, it will take weeks at this rate to finish running!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using *fprintf*:

```
N = 100 ;
M = zeros(1,N) ;
filename1 = 'test1.csv';
t1 = tic ;
for a=1:N
   for b=1:N
      M(1,b)=rand;
   end
   dlmwrite(filename1,M,'-append')

end
t1 = toc(t1) ;

filename2 = 'test2.csv';
M = zeros(1,N) ;
t2 = tic ;
fid = fopen(filename2,'w') ;
for a=1:N
   for b=1:N
      M(1,b)=rand;
   end
   fprintf(fid, [repmat(' %f ', 1, N) '\n'], M') ;

end
fclose(fid) ;
t2 = toc(t2) ;

fprintf('time taken using dlmwrite:%f\n',t1)
fprintf('time taken using fprintf:%f\n',t2)
```

Comment: It took me 67.90 seconds with `fprintf`, so almost identical to that with `dlmwrite`.

Comment: For me....for N = 1000;  time taken using dlmwrite:13.147731,
time taken using fprintf:3.186585